# identify products from a data file string

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I need to identify which products a subscriber has in data file field so I don't show him/her the same products in the email. e.g. the column header called "Products" has this value: product 1 || product 2 || product 4 || product 7. In this case this subscriber will receive 3, 6 and 8.

They use || in between products as per my example.

How can I identify what products are there through AMPscript?

Thanks, Vic

Answer (score 3):

Please utilizing the [BuildRowSetFromString()](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/content_ampscript_functions/#BuildRowSetFromString) AmpScript function.

Here's a quick example:

`%%[
SET @productValues = BuildRowsetFromString("product 1 || product 2 || product 4 || product 7","||")
    For @i = 1 to RowCount(@productValues) DO
        SET @Row = Field(Row(@productValues, @i),1)
        outputline(concat("<br>Product:", @Row)) 
    Next @i

]%%`

Output:

`Product:product 1 
Product: product 2 
Product: product 4 
Product: product 7`

Comment: Thanks Palash, but I need each product assigned to a variable, i.e. @product1, product2, ..., product7. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will work for you.

```
%%[

 SET @productValues = BuildRowsetFromString("product 1 || product 2 || product 4 || product 7","||")
For @i = 1 to RowCount(@productValues) DO
    SET @Row = Field(Row(@productValues, @i),1)

    If IndexOf(@Row,"1")!=0 Then
        SET @Product1 = @Row
    ElseIf IndexOf(@Row,"2")!=0 Then
        SET @Product2 = @Row
    ElseIf IndexOf(@Row,"3")!=0 Then
        SET @Product3 = @Row
    ElseIf IndexOf(@Row,"4")!=0 Then
        SET @Product4 = @Row
    ElseIf IndexOf(@Row,"5")!=0 Then
        SET @Product5 = @Row
    ElseIf IndexOf(@Row,"6")!=0 Then
        SET @Product6 = @Row
    ElseIf IndexOf(@Row,"7")!=0 Then
        SET @Product7 = @Row
    ElseIf IndexOf(@Row,"8")!=0 Then
        SET @Product8 = @Row
    EndIf

Next @i

]%%
```